# How to apply font-family style span across the columns

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have recently learnt that, you can span `background-color` style across the columns of table using `<colgroup>` tag.

```css
table {
     border: 2px solid;
     border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
     border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col span="3" style="background-color:silver">
        <col span="2" style="background-color:green">
        <col span="1" style="background-color:blue">
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As the code given above applies, the first three columns of the table will have silver bg color, the next two will have green bg color and the last next will have blue.

Now my inquiry is, can I similarly span other styles (more specifically the `font-family` attribute) to multiple columns? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript May be helpful to you, this is my code,

```
<table id='myTable'>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br> 

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
let rows=document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;

    for(let i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {
        // from col 1 to col 3
        for(let j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            document.getElementById("myTable").rows[i].cells[j].style.fontFamily='verdana';
            document.getElementById("myTable").rows[i].cells[j].style.background='silver'   
        }
        // from col 4 to col 6
        for(let j=3;j<6;j++){
            document.getElementById("myTable").rows[i].cells[j].style.fontFamily='times new roman';
            document.getElementById("myTable").rows[i].cells[j].style.background='green'    
       }
       // the last one
        for(let j=6;j<7;j++){
            document.getElementById("myTable").rows[i].cells[j].style.fontFamily='arial';
            document.getElementById("myTable").rows[i].cells[j].style.background='blue' 
       }
    } 

}
</script>
```

Comment: Wow!! How do you do that without the button? Too bad I don't know JavaScript yet.

Comment: we can do it on body load `<body onload="myFunction()">`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not how the `colgroup` functions. You can not apply font-related properties inside `colgroup`. You can read a bit more about the available options for styles [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#columns), but it looks like the only style properties you can apply are `border`, `width`, `visibility`, and `background`.

You will need to apply the font styles individually to each `th` or `td` tag in your `table`. This is annoying, but using proper style declarations instead of inline style can at least make it a bit quicker.

```css
.verdana {
  font-family:"verdana";
}
.arial {
  font-family:arial;
}
.times {
  font-family:times new roman;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col span="3" style="background-color:red">
    <col span="2" style="background-color:green">
    <col span="1" style="background-color:blue">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th class="verdana">verdana</th>
    <th class="verdana">verdana</th>
    <th class="verdana">verdana</th>
    <th class="arial">arial</th>
    <th class="arial">arial</th>
    <th class="times">times NR</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="verdana">verdana</th>
    <th class="verdana">verdana</th>
    <th class="verdana">verdana</th>
    <th class="arial">arial</th>
    <th class="arial">arial</th>
    <th class="times">times NR</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks but this requires me to enter class name inside every `<th>` or `<td>` tag I want to apply. Which is a pretty rigorous process if my table is large enough.

Comment: @MerajAlMaksudMasuk yes exactly. The functionality you want is not possible.